# Open command window here with taskbar issues

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Whilst holding the shift key and opening a CMD window in a folder this results in a CMD window being opened that is displayed as a `Prezi Desktop` window in the taskbar.

See this example: http://prntscr.com/aatax

I have no idea why this happens. When I open CMD normally it works flawlessly.

My registry entry looks normal: http://prntscr.com/aatdu

Regards,

Robert

Comment: I think I came closer to the problem. The problem with the wrong taskbar icon results from changing the icon of a shortcut that I use. This shortcut links to a batch file in the following way: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\Bob\Applications\settime.bat"`. Hence there seems to be no way to change the icon of the shortcut but still having the CMD icon displayed in the taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem. It occurred when replacing the CMD icon with an icon from an application folder. Somehow Windows then uses this icon every time when a CMD window is opened, ant not only in the particular case of opening the shortcut which runs the bat file.

Anyway, to avoid this behaviour do not choose an icon from an application folder but rather copy the icon you want to a different location and rename it to avoid any misleading behaviour.